# nested ng-repeat with one index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code, and I want to have one index for all the items in the second ng-repeat
Right now the indexes looks like this:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
```

And if I searh "qwe" I want it to look like this

```
0 0
0 1 
0 2
```

How can I achieve that (Please notice the ng-if that filters the text)?

```js
var app = angular.module('github', []);
app.controller('githubRepos', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){  
  $scope.text = '';
   $scope.groups = {
     1: ['asd', 'asd1', 'asd2'],
     2: ['qwe', 'qwe1', 'qwe2']
   }
  
  $scope.show = function(text) {
    return !$scope.text || text.indexOf($scope.text) !== -1;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="github">
  <div ng-controller="githubRepos">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" />
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
      <div ng-repeat="item in group track by $index" ng-if="show(item)">
        {{parentIndex}} {{$index}} {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are all of the groups the same length?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

> {{parentIndex}} {{$index + (group.length * parentIndex)}} {{item}}

Comment: Now I feel stupid that I didn't think of that :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: there is only one problem... I want the counting reset on search, I updates my description

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div ng-app="github">
  <div ng-controller="githubRepos">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" />
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
      <div ng-repeat="item in group track by $index" ng-if="show(item)">
        {{parentIndex}} {{$index + group.length * parentIndex}} {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any kind of problem with it comment on it

Comment: I need the indexes to change according to search... I updated my description